# aapt_rules.txt not found when build library with Proguard

Tags: android, gradle, build, proguard

I have an Android lib and generate AAR file using [android library plugin](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html) and [fat-aar-plugin](https://github.com/Vigi0303/fat-aar-plugin), but now I need obfuscate code and I write a few simple rules (keep class only) on my .pro file, and add `minifyEnabled true` on my build.gradle

The problem is when try make the project and received this error:

```
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/ninja/Development/Projects/Android/Cloud/CloudSDK-Core-Android/build/intermediates/proguard-rules/debug/aapt_rules.txt (No such file or directory)
Error:Execution failed for task ':CloudSDK-Core-Android:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug'.
> Job failed, see logs for details
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try deleting build folder. Maybe there is something in previous intermediates folder already cached.

Comment: This answer is more appropriate as a comment. If you don't have the reputation to comment yet, wait until you do.